# "Cannot copy extracted data for .. to .." iOS 9.3.5 iPhone 4s Cydia error

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I have recently jailbroken my iPhone 4s on iOS 9.3.5. Whenever I try to install a tweak I get this error message:

[image]

I have looked everywhere and I realized that the problem is because of having less available storage on device. However, I have 4 GB available. I have also installed 'Stashing iOS 9.2 - 10.2' but I still get this error.

Comment: How much system storage do you have? Maybe that's low. You can check in Cydia.

Comment: Me too! How to fix this? I can't even install MobileTerminal or other tweaks because of this. I have more storage. 

Comment: And they say just click refresh in cydia because they are the same as Apt get update. But that's not working.